# Adding additional fields to existing wordpress elementor widget

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have an existing Elementor widget. I want to add a new textfield. Is it possible to add something like the following;

```
$this->add_control(
    'bottom_content',
    [
        'label'       => 'Some label,
        'type'        => Controls_Manager::TEXTAREA,
        'placeholder' => 'Enter content',
        'default'     => 'I am some default',
        'label_block' => true,
    ]
);
```

and then override the `render()` method to display how i like it.

Can I do this from a child theme?